# How can I install jcodec on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days with no success. I am beginner to android programming and I in my project I need to convert few images to a video..I figured out that I can use jcodec for this but I am not able to install it. I would be of great help if someone can tell me how to do this and also provide the necessary links. Also if there is another alternative way to convert images to video please do let me know.

Comment: I think this link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643046/how-to-convert-images-into-video-in-android-using-javacv

Comment: Thanks a lot....I'll look into it and let you know if I face any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the jcodec from here:
 http://jcodec.org/downloads.html

Next, copy the lib file to the "libs" directory in the project, do "project->properties->Java build->Libraries->add jar" and select the lib jcodec.jar from the project's libs directory.

For building the video from frames take a look at:
[Android make animated video from list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To use JCodec in your android app simply add this to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.1.9'
}
```

This way you pull all the Android specific classes as well as 'org.jcodec:jcodec' on which this artifact transitively depends.

You can refer to Android sample app here: https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/tree/master/android/sample

Simply check it out from git and open in your Android Studio.