# Converting a set of images into a video using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I tried the code which I found in this link-
[how to convert images into video in android using javacv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643046/how-to-convert-images-into-video-in-android-using-javacv)

But I had a handful of error - [image]

I have included opencv 2.4.6 -

[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem...

Also If you know how to convert a set of images into a video using opencv please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with OpenCV, but with you project settings (generally). [Here](https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=cr&ei=SIVaUp61HMXNswaL_4GoAQ#q=eclipse%20android%20project%20has%20no%20project.properties%20file) you will find lot of solutions, if you will still have problems give us more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help..but my question actually was - 
I am getting an error on import lines i.e 

at 
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage;

and others

I am getting an error - The import com.googlecode cannot be resolved.

I am getting this even though I have included opencv...Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this type of problem before. Don't forget to manually add the .jar files on your project's lib folder. Although it is not a requirement, I solved mine by doing so. Then import the .jar files and add it to your project's build path.