# Combine images to video stream

Tags: opencv, android-studio, image-processing, ffmpeg, javacv

Can anyone please tell what is the easiest way to complete topic task in android studio?
I found some solutions but was unable to set to work any of them.

1. One suggestion was to use FFmpeg recorder like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643182/5991151). Problem is recorder takes only `IplImage` type. I tried to create `IplImage` with `javacv.cpp.opencv_core`, but it refers to `java.awt.*` stuff, which is not supported by android, so i catch crash. Moreover, using `IplImage` is highly unlikely because it is old format and because transformations of `Mat` (that's type that i have) to `IplImage` takes a lot of formating steps with `byte[]`, `BufferedImage` and other types of one to another.
2. Another way i tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463719/ffmpegmultiple-image-frames-1-audio-1-video/21304505#21304505). It looked acceptable - to process multiple `.jpeg` to video stream with codecs. But as far as i understand problem is that FFmpeg is not provided as complete stand-alone SDK lib for android. And almost all web-links to source FFmpeg-files which could contain methods (like `execFFMPEG`) are already dead.

In general, topic task must not be hard: to combine simple video stream with given set of images, fixed fps and video coder (i don't even need audio stream). In practice, i'm already overheaded with tones of infos and still not a step closer to solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution - i used `IplImage.cvLoadImage(filename)` and loaded image from SD-card without any problem. Before i used `IplImage.create` and it wasn't working. Though referencing to `java.awt*` still remains, turns out this is not the problem for compiler.

And FFMpeg recorder works fine. [Here's](https://github.com/pals/screenCaptureVideoOpenCV) a working example (not mine) of FFmpeg realisation if anyone would need it.